# How can I get coordinates from userlocation?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

How can I get the latitude and longtitude from `mapView.userLocation`?

I need that to get the distance between userLocation and another point on the map.

I hope you can help me and thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Use the method provided in `CLLocation`:

`- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location`